# what really happened to my virtualenv that I cant use pip

Tags: python, pip

So I have a couple questions regarding `virtualenv` and `pip`.

I have a `virtualenv` that's been around for weeks and `pip` works fine in it but suddenly it stopped working it showed this error when I tried to do `pip freeze`

```
Unable to create process using ' "PATH"  "PATH" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Now I can only use `python -m pip freeze` instead of `pip freeze` Why is this ?,  I've read it somewhere that it was caused by the path being too long or having a space in the path, None of this is true in my case

I also made a new `virtualenv` on the same directory to test if `pip` would've worked in it and it did. I've also made sure that python version on my `virtualenv` is the same one installed on my local machine .I'm able to run `pip freeze` on the new `virtualenv` but not the older ones.

To summarize my questions

1. Why is my `pip` suddenly stopped working?
2. Why `python -m pip` works but `pip` didn't work?

Comment: if you call `which pip` in your virenv, is it the correct `pip` it returns?

Comment: @CutePoison no it didn't. I figured it out thanks to you. The `pip` in my `virtualenv` is outdated. you can write an answer if you want so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `which pip` in your virenv from the terminal to see, if it's the correct pip that's being used.